# ABAP Unit tests are only detected / executable right after generating. How to make the test class visible?

Tags: unit-testing, abap

I'm trying to write **unit tests** for my class in ABAP but when I write the code manually in Eclipse, the IDE tells me there is no test class and no executable tests. If I use the **wizard in SAP GUI**, the generated test works and I can replace it with my test - which then also works - but when I close the SAP GUI and reopen it again, it **doesn't detect** any test class or executable tests again.

It seems like a bug to me or some issue with the **SAP** version I am using:

*SAP NETWEAVER  7.4 15 (06/2016)    sap.com SAP NETWEAVER 7.4*

I'm a beginner ABAP programmer but I already successfully covered another one of my classes with test and I have no problems there. The only difference is that the other class runs on a different system with higher version of SAP - 7.5.

Have you encountered issue like this?

Comment: Did you check if there are some patches in the SAP support website?

Comment: Posting a small example how you do this in Eclipse would be very helpful, so that all could be able reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few days of light research I found out there is a **SAP Note 2598526** which pretty much describes the issue I have.

For the future reference it states that:

> **Reason and Prerequisites:**
>   The ABAP unit test framework calls the class CL_ABAP_COMPILER to determine the test classes from the current program. However, the call of the class CL_ABAP_COMPILER terminates with an internal error.
>
> **Solution:**
>   If the description applies to your situation, please install a new kernel that contains the patch "ABAP-SYCH: Dumped TYPES table has dangling type ids".

Right now we will try to patch the kernel and I will let you know if that helps.

EDIT 06/05/2019:

So... the patch didn't help with this issue but it looks like I finally found a solution. There are three steps to it:

1. Open SE03 and make sure the namespace is listed here with **development license** and in **production role (P)**
2. Open report: **SATC_AC_INIT_NAMESPACE_REG** and register the namespace to the ATC (ABAP Test Cockpit) - otherwise the cockpit will ignore the namespace and won't scan it for test classes.
3. The registration of the namespace will create a request so transport it and reactive the class that has unit tests.

When you do this, you should be able to run the tests - in both SAP GUI and Eclipse no problem :).

Comment: Additionally, also check that the risk level limit is allowed on that system via transaction `SAUNIT_CLIENT_SETUP`.